# Hard Drive dead after windows 10 failed install

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

Earlier today, I attempted to reset windows 10 on my hard drive, which worked perfectly prior to doing so. I let the reset wizard take over, and for 4 straight hours, it said it was getting files ready. So I figured it had either finished and not told me, or hadn't started. So I turned off my pc, as it wasn't going anywhere anytime soon. Loading back into uefi, I checked to see if I could boot to it, and the UEFI didn't even acknowledge the existence of an internal drive. I put it in an enclosure to see if windows saw it, and it didn't. I finally used gParted live to check and see, and it saw nothing as well. I think it's a dead hard drive, but it's faster than my current, and I'm sure its not a hardware issue.

Can anyone help me figure out how to recover the thing?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it was a hard drive failure.  The drive was a seagate.  They seem to have had a bad run lately.  Did you put the external drive on a USB 3.0 port?  My drive would not work on a 2.0, but did (for a while) on the 3.0.  When I eventually did a reinstall on a different 1T drive the process did take a VERY long time; I left it overnight but it did complete.  I hope you have an image backup.

Good luck.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more specific. It was an INTERNAL drive, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thought I replied but I don't see it.  I did understand that this is the internal drive but you did say you put it into an enclosure.  I assumed this was external.  If not, how did you do it?

Comment: Oh. Yeah, its an external enclosure, but would it make a difference if the direct sata connection won't even work?

Comment: Not sure what you meant by direct sata connection.  Is that the connection for the internal drive?  You did say that the O/S couldn't recognize it as an internal drive but that could be a cable or the HDD itself.  If you tried the HDD in an external case and put it into USB 2.0 and 3.0 ports and it doesn't work, then the drive has likely failed.  If that is the case the option for recovery is by a specialized company and my understanding is that the cost is prohibitive; that it could be in the thousands.

Comment: I know the cable is fine, I'm using it right now, for a much slower hard drive

Comment: Summary:  The HDD is not recognized when in the computer drive bay connected by the internal cable and I assuming you have either booted from and external drive or are using a recovery disk.  The HDD, when installed, in an external sata case and connected to either a USB 2.0 or 3.0 port is not recognized by the O/S when booted from another internally mounted HDD, a recovery boot, or booting from an external drive.  The conclusion is that either the I/F board on the HDD has failed or the HDD has experienced a mechanical failure.  Conclusion:  The data on the HDD is non-recoverable.

Comment: *sighs* That's a shame. It was only my work in 2016, probably not my best either. Thanks for your time.

Comment: No problem.  I know it is tiresome to say, but do you do regular backups?  I didn't but since my disaster, I do.  Fortunately I had done one "just in case" when I swapped the HDD just before the entire computer and the HDD collapsed.  The Motherboard, io cards, cables, and HDD were replaced, the HDD three times.  It works now, but during the three months of attemped repairs, I bought another computer.  Now it do the following every friday:  Using the backups from the control panel:  image backup, user backup.  I also copy of all user directories  to an externally 1T file backup drive.

Comment: Yeah, I do yearly backups. Bit of a gamble, just bad timing that it happens 5 days before the backup was scheduled.